# Removing a AngularJS component from the DOM and from his parent on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

i'm trying to show a **list of users** in AngularJS

Each one would be user with a custom component element
The components would have TWO buttons

- First one have to remove the component element from the DOM ( and destroy watchers etc.. ) but don't alter the list of users.
- Second one have to remove the component, AND the user from the list

[I have prepare this sample case in Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/woQKYvyyiGla6UUEJAeh)

---

```
// app.controller.js
// ///////////////////

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  function MainController( $log, $scope ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "I'm the Parent controller";

    vm.users = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Rob', color: 'slategrey'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Ned', color: 'snow'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Ramsey', color: 'palevioletred'}
    ];
  }
})();



// Component Controller
// /////////////////////////

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ComponentController', ComponentController);

  function ComponentController() {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.removeMe = removeMe;
    $ctrl.removeMeFromAll = removeMeFromAll;

    function removeMe(){
      //angular.element.remove();
      //$ctrl.$destroy();

      // Magic goes here 
      // .............
    }

    function removeMeFromAll(userID) {
      // Magic goes here 
      // .............
    } 
  }
})();
```

I have been searching and seeing the way used for directives with the link element, but cannot figure out how to apply here.

Comment: if you don't want items to be visible in the dom, use `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, or `ng-if`, and allow angular to deal with the DOM manipulation.  if you are trying to override how angular is managing the DOM, then you aren't likely using the framework as intended.

Comment: Hi @Claies, i'm not trying to override how angular works,
indeed i'm trying to use his $destroy methods to remove unused $whatchers for that case where the DOM elements are no longer needed.

ng-hide just applied a display: none.
and ng-if not allow styles for a soft visual elimination

But i'm no sure about how to do that, thats why i created the sample case.

Maybe i explained wrong, but what i want to achieve is using the best Angular available